# JBoss EAP 7.2 EJB Server to client communication without http

Tags: java, swing, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

We are using JBoss EAP 7.2 to deploy EJB server application and EJB client is Swing based application.
We have a requirement to detect the EJB clients which is no longer active(due to application crash)so that EJB server application can terminate the open database session associated with client.

Is there any way within EJB/JBoss EAP 7.2 which can allow server application to ping/send heartbeat to detect if client is still alive?

Http based mechanism may be problematic as firewall permissions will create issues.

Comment: How does your client currently communicate with the server?

Comment: I am very confused as to how you plan on bypassing those firewall permissions with those EJB clients. What protocol do you plan to use and how will you tunnel that through the firewall? You seem to be operating at an odd level of granularity in your design, normally you want some sort of asynchronous call back - what kind of request patterns are you using?

Comment: its over remoting-http protocol(client context) provided by JBoss,
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:28081}"/>
So client uses this port in client context to invoke EJB from server